# How to return focus to scanner after user input?

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner, user-input

I'm taking in a numeric input from a user using the scanner class.
But after the calculation has completed I want to return to the initial prompt for input.

```
//get user input 
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
String fibMaxNum;

System.out.println("Enter the highest fibonacci number: ");
fibMaxNum = user_input.next();
```

Does anyone know how I can acheive this in code?

I've tried to return the control to the initial input by adding a `return` statement but this has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the highest fibonacci number: ");
    fibMaxNum = user_input.next();
    if (fibMaxNum < 0) break;
    //process fibMaxNum.
} while (true);
```